# Mathematical expectation calculated in two ways

Tags: probability, expected-value

Suppose that $\Omega$ is the set of all functions $f: X \longrightarrow Y$, where $X = \{1, 2, ..., n\}$ and $Y = \{0, 1, ..., m - 1\}$ and n > m, such that the probability that an element $i \in X$ is mapped to any of the elements in $Y$ is $\frac{1}{m}$. Consider $X_{j}: \Omega \longrightarrow \{0, 1, ..., n\} \;\;(0 \leq j \leq m - 1)$ as a random variable calculating the number of elements of $X$ that are mapped to $j$ by $f$. Then the expected value of $X_{j}$ is $\frac{n}{m}$. However, I found the following formula for the expected value since looks like we can model it by multinomial distribution:
$$\sum_{i = 0}^{n} {n \choose i} \frac{(n - 1)^{n - i}}{m^{n}}i$$
We need to choose an image for each element of $X$ under $f$ so it's like we are repeating a random experiment with $m$ outcomes $n$ times so as to induce a function $f$. As a result, we have a multinomial distribution. We know the expected value is $\sum_{i = 0}^{n} p_{i}i$ where $p_{i}$ is the probability that is induced by $X_{j}$. We should choose $i$ elements so as to set their images as $j$ and then multiply it by $\frac{1}{m^{i}}$ and the other $n - i$ elements can have any other number in $Y$ as an image so the probability of that is $\frac{1}{m^{n - i}}(n - 1)^{n - i}$. Overall, the probability would be ${n \choose i} \frac{(n - 1)^{n - i}}{m^{n}}i$. So the expected value should be $\sum_{i = 0}^{n} {n \choose i} \frac{(n - 1)^{n - i}}{m^{n}}i$.

But these two are not equal. So where is the problem? I haven't taken Probability $1$ yet. That's why I can't solve this problem.

Comment: How did you justify your second formula? Hint: Try it out with small values, for example $n=2$ and $m=1$. What numerical value do you get? Could it even possibly be correct?

Comment: @JukkaKohonen I edited my post.

Comment: It is harder to follow your reasoning than it ought to be. You could fix this by being more careful to say exactly what you mean at each stage. For example, "the expected value is $\sum_{i = 0}^{n} p_{i}i$" -- the expected value of what? What does $i$ signify in this formula? The first time you mention $i$ it is a single element of $X$ that is mapped to an element of $Y$. But apparently now you mean $i$ is the *number of elements* of $X$ that are mapped to $j.$ It is lucky that someone had the patience to figure out enough of your meaning to spot the mistake.

Comment: @DavidK I realized my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formula for the expected value of $\ X_j\ $ is incorrect. Each element of $\ X\ $ gets mapped to $\ j\ $ with probability $\ \frac{1}{m}\ $ and some other element of $\ Y\ $ with probability $\ 1-\frac{1}{m}\ $. The distribution of $\ X_j\ $ is therefore [binomial $\ B\Big(n,\frac{1}{m}\Big)\ $](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) and its expected value is
$$
\sum_{i=0}^ni{n\choose i}\Big(\frac{1}{m}\Big)^i\Big(1-\frac{1}{m}\Big)^{n-i}=\frac{n}{m}\ .
$$

Comment: I understand why your solution is true but where did I make a mistake so that my final solution got wrong? I think it should have a multinomial solution as well. Of course, it will require more calculation.

Comment: The only error in your formula is the numerator $\ n-1\ $ of the fraction $\ \frac{(n-1)^{n-i}}{m^n}\ $ inside the sum.  It should instead be $\ m-1\ $, in which case you have $\ \frac{(m-1)^{n-i}}{m^n}=\Big(\frac{1}{m}\Big)^i\Big(1-\frac{1}{m}\Big)^{n-i}\ $ (which I didn't notice earlier) which would give you the correct answer.  If $\ n=m\ $ it wouldn't make any difference, but I don't understand why you've put $\ n-1\ $ instead of $\ m-1\ $ in the numerator.

Comment: If $\ n\ne m\ $ then $\ \sum_\limits{i=0}^n{n\choose i}\frac{(n-1)^{n-i}}{m^n}=\big(\frac{n}{m}\big)^n\ne1\ $, so $\ {n\choose i}\frac{(n-1)^{n-i}}{m^n}\ $ is not even a proper probability mass function.

Comment: Ah, I made a terrible mistake. I thought the number of elements of $Y$ that are left is $n - 1$ rather than $m - 1$. I see now. This multinomial approach gives the same answer as yours. Thanks.